# What is a polynomial approximation?

Tags: polynomials, approximation

Is it possible for a dummy like me who is really bad at math to explain what a polynomial approximation is? Is it possible to give a simple, but illustrative example?

I just googled the term and found that I stumbled on some vague or obscure (for me) terms and symbols on all the pages and, thus, couldn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will enlighten you. In blue, the function $\sin(x)$. In green, the polynomial $x-\dfrac{x^3}6$. In magenta, the polynomial $x-\dfrac{x^3}6+\dfrac{x^5}{120}$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! So, the green one and the magenta one are approximations, right?

Comment: @brilliant: in fact, all are approximations of each other...

Comment: Polynomials are typically easy to calculate so if you can find a good polynomial approximation then you may be able to use that.  It is common, as you see here, that the approximation is good in a limited area but poor further away.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - Ah, I got it. Thank you!

Comment: @badjohn - Thank you! "that the approximation is good in a limited area but poor further away" - Which makes me think that polynomial approximations are useless. But I guess their practical applications is a topic for a separate question.

Comment: Actually, they are very useful but you need to understand when they are good and when they aren't.  $\sin$ is a good example.  From its properties, you can see that it is enough to calculate it in the range $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$. With a little more effort, you can see that $(0, \frac{\pi}{4})$ is enough.  So, if your polynomial is good in these limited ranges then they are useful.

Comment: @badjohn - I see. Thank you. I was too quick in stating that they are useless.

Comment: Try to find out what your calculator or computer is actually doing when you ask it to calculate $\sin$.

Comment: @brilliant: the point is that functions such as the sine are defined in a way that requires an infinity of arithmetic operations, which is not really practical with a computer :-) Hence you do need approximations. But we are able to make approximations that cannot be distinguished from the real functions in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Yves Daoust provided an approximation using a Taylor series, which gives a good approximation near one point.

Here is an illustration of Chebyshev's [equioscillation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equioscillation_theorem): it's possible to find a polynomial that is a good approximation on a whole interval.

For instance, an approximation of degree $3$ of $\sin(x)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is given by the polynomial:

$$- 0.0000000534717177+ 0.8245351702\,x+ 0.00000008122122864\,{x}^{2}\\-
 0.08691931647\,{x}^{3}$$

*(this approximation was found using [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=numapprox/minimax))*

Here is a plot of this polynomial and $\sin(x)$:

[image]

These minimax approximations have the nice property that the difference with the function *oscillates* between two bounds. Here is the difference:

[image]

Comment: For the OP's understanding: the vertical scale of the error plot is different.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting!

Comment: @YvesDaoust - Thank you for this remark, I was just trying to understand that by myself and couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a function $f$ defined on a certain domain. A polynomial approximation of $f$ is a polynomial $p$ that is the most closest approximation to $f$ given certain conditions..

Now, of course if $f$ is not a polynomial and the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ then $p$ will never get close enough to $f$. But for example if you consider a compact interval and a function $f$ that is quite regular, then the magic happens: this is Weierstrass' theorem.

**Note:**
What I wrote before is quite vague, so let be more clear:
Consider the interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb R$ and a function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$. We say that a polynomial $p$ is a good approximation of $f$ if the maximum distance from $p$ to $f$ all over $[a,b]$ is less than a tolerance we decide, or in math language
$$ \forall x \in [a,b] \, \, \,\text{we have} \, \, \, |p(x) - f(x) | < TOL $$

Weierstrass' theorem says:
Given a continous function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ then there exists a sequence of polynomials $(p_n)$ that converges uniformly to $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$. In other terms:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x\in [a,b]} |p(x) - f(x) | = 0$$

This is only an example. There exists so many theorems about approximation.

Comment: "I stumbled on some vague or obscure (for me) terms and symbols on all the pages"

Comment: I have been vague at the beginning, but I think I have given enough details in the "second part" of the answer. The OP wanted a simple example and this is what I've done.

Comment: Thank you, but it would be better for me if you used some visual illustrations like graphs as examples. Honestly, whatever follows the word "Note" is already quite hard for me to understand because you use a lot of symbols in there that I am not familiar with.